hexo next theme inline math render support
My next theme can not render inline math with $$
even when I did the setup as below:

package

npm uninstall hexo-renderer-marked
npm install hexo-renderer-pandoc


config.yaml

per_page:true
  mathjax:
    enable: true


post formatter
mathjax: true

attach files:




The only thing I could image is that the pandoc pug was installed in another enironment  so that the render was offset.

I avoid it  by using markeddown it.
